# storing the updated timestamp whenevr the query from that particular table is called

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store the time at which the table was accessed/modified. I know how to put current timestamp.

But what we must do to store the updated timestamp ?

Comment: if you want to keep a track of all the updations of all the table, just create a new table with fields (table_name and timestamp) and insert the last updated time in this table for each table operation

Comment: You should really be able to determine the answer to your question on your own, given the fact you know what a timestamp is and how to "put" it.

Comment: Which is the your database/table structure? Do you have any field to store the last_access timestamp? Do you have written any query?

Comment: You want to know when there is UPDATE or UPDATE AND SELECT on your rows? .. for update there is standard option - ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP .. For updating on SELECT you may use Trigger..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for but below query might be helpful.
you can create/upate your table to have "[On Update Current_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)"

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To update a timestamp when accessing a record you could use a stored procedure to `select` the records and then `update` the timestamp fields.

@Suresh Kamrushi has suggested a solution for updating the timestamp when the record is modified.